# Return code 255 when trying to connect via ssh with barman

Tags: postgresql, barman

When I do a manual ssh connection it is working fine. But when I run `barman check 192.168.0.41` it is giving me `ssh : FAILED with return code 255`

I have tried all methods that they explained in the pgbarman document like copying public keys and saving it in `authorized_keys`.

```
barman@icms-liq:~$ barman check 192.168.0.41
Server 192.168.0.41:

        empty incoming directory: FAILED ('/var/lib/barman/192.168.0.41/incoming' must be empty when archiver=off)

        PostgreSQL: OK
        is_superuser: OK
        PostgreSQL streaming: OK
        wal_level: OK
        replication slot: OK
        directories: OK
        retention policy settings: OK
        backup maximum age: FAILED (interval provided: 2 days, latest backup age: No available backups)
        compression settings: OK
        failed backups: OK (there are 0 failed backups)
        minimum redundancy requirements: FAILED (have 0 backups, expected at least 1)
        ssh: FAILED (Connection failed using 'ssh postgres@192.168.0.41 -o BatchMode=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' return code 255)
        pg_receivexlog: OK
        pg_receivexlog compatible: OK
        receive-wal running: OK
        archiver errors: OK
```

Comment: Did you try the same command manually that the error message shows?

Comment: yes and its giving me this -- barman@icms-liq:~$ ssh postgres@192.168.0.41 -o BatchMode=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
postgres@192.168.0.41: Permission denied (publickey,password).

Comment: There's the root problem you have to solve. What is the command for the manual connection that is working for you?

Comment: ssh postgres@192.168.0.41

Comment: Ok, be creative. Check which of the two options is your problem. Turn on debugging etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my doubts. It worked when i installed without giving password.